# Structural equation modelling in lavaan

Tags: r, regression, p-value, structural-equation-modeling, lavaan

I used factor analysis and structural equation modelling using `lavaan` in RStudio. Before adding the residual covariances and regression into the SEM model, the model failed the chi-square test. After adding the residual covariances, the model satisfied this test and all other goodness of fit tests.

However, while running the model I got a warning message related to the variances, the p-value of a observed variable is high. Adding regressions made no change in the model results. Since, I am new to structural equation modelling and learning from online resources, I don't know whether this model is mis-specified or good.

I added the output of the model. Please let me know what is wrong here.

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: To those voting to close this question, I recommend keeping it open as this question pertains to troubleshooting model specification moreso than it is a programming question, which necessarily requires the mention of `lavaan` given the tools used for estimation in this question.

Comment: I vtc due to it being asking two different questions at the same time and also imo it still lacks some information from OP's part. I have removed the reference part and voted to reopen @ShawnHemelstrand.

Comment: Fair enough. To the discretion of people here.

Comment: I agree with @ShawnHemelstrand that the question is absolutely relevant and should not be closed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

##### Troubleshooting

Christian already made some informative remarks about your Heywood cases and potential model mis-specification via two-item factors. Without a lot of context about your predictors/outcomes, it is hard to give any real concrete advice, but as Christian mentioned already, a lot of what's wrong with this model may come down simply to the model not matching your data (this is not unique to SEM...this is also common with linear mixed models as well). Keep in mind that I am not an expert in SEM, but some common culprits for model issues (including Heywood cases) include:

- Extreme collinearity (e.g. variables that have a correlation over .80 or a VIF over 10) can contribute to instability in the estimates.
- The opposite can also be true, where sparse covariance between variables that are otherwise specified as correlated can lead to failure in the model. This can lead to stuff like non-positive definite (NPD) matrices, wherein a solution cannot be derived because there is simply no meaningful variance to estimate.
- Variables that are are completely different scales can often cause issues with the iterative algorithms that estimate SEMs. If you have something like median income (in 10,000s) along with a variable like number of children in the household (in single digits), this can cause some serious issues at times and so scaling measures may need to be taken.
- Estimation on non-normal distributions using maximum likelihood (ML), which assumes multivariate normality, can also sometimes contribute to Heywood cases. Transformation may be necessary if data is heavily skewed, nonlinear, or has other features that make ML problematic (other estimation methods may be used to counteract this, but I would educate yourself on those methods).
- Typically small samples also contribute to this issue, but it looks like you have a pretty sizeable sample, so that is likely not the culprit.
- Problematic missingness can also be a contributor.

Some things you can do to tackle this may include:

- Checking your data distributions, correlations, etc. to see if any of the above is true and taking measures to correct them. For example, if you have two variables that are highly correlated, you can determine whether or not it may be better to simply remove the variable altogether from the model. Using matrix tools in R like checking the determinant of your covariance matrix (such as `det(cov.matrix)`) may also spot if this is an issue.
- Setting the variance equal to its actual value in the observed data. For example, if Q17.4 has a variance of 20, you can model that explicitly in `lavaan` as `Q.17.4 ~~ 20*Q17.4`
- Alternatively, you can simply set the variance to zero, but this implies that the item is measured without error, which can often be unrealistic.

I have provided references to three articles/books that may be helpful to you. The first two are papers that deal with the common problems associated with Heywood cases and some solutions to these problems. The third is a book on SEM that I would argue is probably the most accessible book on SEM out there. If you are new to statistics, I would highly recommend going through the primers that come with the book to educate yourself on some of the underpinnings of SEM that are important (psychometrics, regression, etc.).

Btw Christian has a great YouTube channel [called QuantFish](https://www.youtube.com/@QuantFish) for SEM and factor analysis topics if you are interested in free resources. [Statistics of Doom](https://www.youtube.com/@StatisticsofDOOM) is another good SEM-based channel, along with [CenterStat](https://www.youtube.com/@centerstat). The people who run CenterStat also have a great statistics podcast with several SEM topic-based episodes, called [Quantitude](https://quantitudepod.org/).

#### References

- Chen, F., Bollen, K. A., Paxton, P., Curran, P. J., & Kirby, J. B. (2001). Improper solutions in structural equation models: Causes, consequences, and strategies. Sociological Methods & Research, 29(4), 468–508. https://doi.org/10.1177/0049124101029004003
- Dillon, W. R., & Kumar, A. (1987). Offending estimates in covariance structure analysis: Comments on the causes of and solutions to Heywood cases. Psychological Bulletin, 101(1), 126–135. https://doi.org/10.1037/0033-2909.101.1.126
- Kline, R. B. (2023). Principles and practice of structural equation modeling (5th ed.). The Guilford Press.

Comment: Thank you for the clarification and the references. It will be very helpful for me.

Comment: Do you feel Christian or myself have adequately answered your original question? If so, feel free to hit the checkmark next to either answer.

Answer (score 6):

You are getting a negative residual variance (improper solution, "Heywood case") for your observed variable Q17.4 (-0.007). A negative residual variance is not interpretable/plausible and usually means there is a problem with the model specification and/or data. One reason could be that you have only two indicators per factor (models with only two indictors per factor can be more prone to improper solutions). Another (or an additional) reason could be that the model may be overparameterized or otherwise misspecified after adding the residual covariances. Did you add those residual covariances based on theory or data-based (e.g., based on modification indices)?

Comment: Yes. Based on modification indices, I added the residual covariances.

Comment: Do you have any theoretical/substantive justification for adding those error covariances? Most SEM experts would advise you to not add error covariances or other parameters only because they are suggested by modification indices because this would be purely data-driven and subject to capitalizing on chance. Also, fit statistics are no longer meaningful after you make post hoc model modifications based on the same set of data.